# Returning a bounding disk or box centered on a coordinate in a 2D image

Tags: image-processing

Provided a coordinate $c_k$ in a two-dimensional image, how can I return all of the pixels in a bounding disk or rectangle centered on $c_k$ of some specified dimension $d$?

**Update:** Hat tip to Kuba for recommending `PixelValue` and Sjoerd C. de Vries for recommending `ImageData`.  However, considering the case of the bounding box, is it possible to return the pixels using:

```
PixelValue[image,
           {Subscript[x, min];;Subscript[x, max],Subscript[y, min];;Subscript[y, max]}]
```

In the form of a matrix rather than a 1-dimensional array?

Comment: Take a look at `PixelValue`.

Comment: Or `ImageData`.

Comment: @Kuba Terrific, thanks!

Comment: About returning a matrix: how would a circular matrix look like?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Apologies, I meant for the bounding box with some $x_{min}$ to $x_{max}$ and $y_{min}$ to $y_{max}$ specified with the indicated command.

Comment: About update, `ImageData` is more natural for that. Anticipating further updates, maybe Your looking for `ImageTrim`?

Comment: You can use `Partition` to bring the list in matrix form. You could have a look at `ImageValue` as well. It returns a matrix given this syntax, but note that it handles  coordinates differently.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, Partition works perfectly.

Comment: So, post the answer to your own question

Answer (score 2):

In order to return a square two-dimensional matrix of pixels with edge dimension $2*k+1$ centered at some point $(c_x,c_y)$ - i.e. we grab $k$ pixels to the right, to the left, above, and below $(c_x,c_y)$ - we can write:

```
data = PixelValue[image, {cx - k ;; cx + k, cy - k ;; cy + k}];
TempArray = Partition[data, 2*k + 1];
```

This can easily be generalized to a rectangular matrix with edge dimensions $k_1 \times k_2$ by writing:

```
data = PixelValue[image, {cx - k1 ;; cx + k1, cy - k2 ;; cy + k2}];
TempArray = Partition[data, 2*k1 + 1];
```

One can also trivially change the offset by slightly modifying the above approach.